# Getting a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Error when deleting a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, exc-bad-instruction

My tableview currently looks like this.

[image]

and here is the code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monthlyCell", for: indexPath) as! MonthlyExpenseTableViewCell

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64

    let expense = expensePerMonth[indexPath.row]

    let date = expense.modificationDate
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMMM"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date! as Date).uppercased()

    CoreDataHelper.save()

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        newMode = true
    }
    if indexPath.row>=1{
        monthlyExpenses.sorted(by: { $0.modificationDate as! Date > $1.modificationDate as! Date})
      let previousExpensesData = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row].modificationDate as! Date) // Do not add above 'date' value here, you might get some garbage value. I know the code is redundant. You can adjust that.
        let previousDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate! as Date)
        if day == previousDay {
            newMode = false
        } else {
            newMode = true
        }
    }


    var expenseAmountCalculating:Double = Double(expense.amount!)!
    var expenseAmountDisplayed:String = convertToMoney(expenseAmountCalculating)

    var finalDisplayed:String = expense.currencySymbol! + " " + expenseAmountDisplayed
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateString
    cell.expenseName2.text = expense.name
    cell.expenseAmount2.text = finalDisplayed
    cell.expenseCategory2.text = expense.category
    cell.expenseCollection2.text = expense.collection
                if (expense.expense) {
                    cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.red
                }


                else if (expense.income){
                    cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor(red:0.49, green:0.83, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
                }

                if (expense.cash) && (expense.expense){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")

                }
                else if (expense.cash) && (expense.income){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")

                }
                else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")

                }
                else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")

                }
    if newMode == false{
        cell.dateLabel.isHidden = true
        tableView.rowHeight = 64
        cell.expenseName2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 11)
        cell.expenseCategory2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 61, y: 33)
        cell.expenseCollection2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 108, y: 33)


    }
    else if newMode == true{
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64

    }
return cell
```

}

As you can see, the expenses are grouped by date. When I delete an expense which is at the top, I want the next expense to take over and show the datelabel. This is the label at the top which shows the dates and is invisible for expenses which already exist for a certain date. However, when I delete an expense, I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at this line:

```
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date! as Date).uppercased()
```

probably because the datelabel is invisible for the cell.

So how do I go about doing this?

The code for deleting the cell is this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        let collection = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row]
        CoreDataHelper.deleteExpense(expense: collection)
        monthlyExpenses.remove(at: indexPath.row )
        monthlyExpenses = CoreDataHelper.retrieveExpenses()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where did you delete the cell?

Comment: I have the added the code

Comment: First, i think you don't need this line `monthlyExpenses.remove(at: indexPath.row )`. Second, did you call `reloadData` or `deleteRow` after delete collection?

Comment: Nope, will try doing that

Comment: You should post the stack trace at the point of exception; it should be pretty clear what's going on from that. (You'll get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION from lots of different failures; I believe Apple's core code generally throws a bad instruction at the processor to stop everything on a runtime error.)